# Vertically center align container div

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a toolbar style navigation menu, where the content is added dynamically into the container.

I want to align the container div's center vertically to the center of the screen.

Here is my approach
http://cssdeck.com/labs/cmwvyjud

I know that this is not how it should be, but I'm unable to find alternative ways of doing this vertical alignment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to use `<span>` elements inside the container div instead of more `<div>`s

Comment: @voidking is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: You may be able to wrap the elements within the container in an inline element and use `vertical-align: middle;` (I use this all the time with my `<td>` elements when necessary).

Comment: @VoidKing There's no reason to switch from div to span

Comment: @cimmanon Why not? Why add extra lines before and after all the contained block elements? Seems like he would have more control (in adding or not adding `</br>`) over inline elements...

Comment: @VoidKing You're suggesting change for the sake of change and recommending additional unnecessary markup.  If the OP wants them to display vertically as they are, then spans make no sense here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a pure CSS solution, you have 2 options.  If you're willing to add an additional container, you could use `display: table`.  If the markup cannot change, then Flexbox is what you're looking for.

## Display: table

http://cssdeck.com/labs/jdzltkla

```
body{
    background-color:black;
}

#container{
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
}

.foo {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#container .foo > * {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

<div id="container">
    <div class="foo">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works in just about everything, including IE8+

## Flexbox

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/sKqkE

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#container {
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

#container * {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This works in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE10, and Safari.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a very good solution too, but I'll go with the javascript one since its cleaner overall

Comment: I've added the `display: table` solution as well, which is much more compact and doesn't require downloading the megalithic jQuery library.

Comment: LOVELY! Definitely THE solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the height of the content that needs to be centered you can take half of that height and use something like `margin-top:-(contentHeight/2)px`

See example at : http://cssdeck.com/labs/atwispr6, here I know the content is 300px, so when I take half I have 150px. So `margin-top:-150px`

**Edit** 
I have updated the example, to make it dynamic

```
    $(function(){
        var $container = $("#container")    
        $container.css("margin-top", "-" + ($container.height()/2) + "px");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The content height is not known (it depends on the number of items inside) - that is why I was stuck.

Comment: You can use jQuery to calculate the height of the content.

Comment: You should include that statement (with an example) in your answer. He might not know how to do that at this time (plus it would greatly improve the quality of your answer).

Answer (score 0):

the content is 300px, screen height is (for Ex 768px), so you must compare your content with screen height, not content itself...

so content is about 40% of screen height, and you can use `top:25%;` for top..

or in jQuery :

```
var container_height = parseInt($("#container").css("height"));
$("#container").css("top", (parseInt((screen.height-container_height)/2))+"px");
```